# Which of the following is a consequence of Selecting model complexity on test data? (multiple right answers)

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, machine-learning-model, model-selection

Selecting model complexity on test data (choose all that apply):

A. Allows you to avoid issues of overfitting to training data

B. Provides an overly optimistic assessment of performance of the resulting model

C. Is computationally inefficient

D. Should never be done

This question is part of a machine learning course I am taking on Coursera that I just realized has poor instructor support and hence I am unable to receive any help.

I am confident that I have understood every little detail of the material that this question is based on. But I have no idea why my answer is wrong, i.e.: A and B

Here is my explanation for why I picked A and B:

Analyzing this question's 4 options:

A. Preventing overfitting and under-fitting of training data is the goal of using tuning parameters to pick the right model complexity, hence using test data for this should achieve the goal/purpose.

B. Given that tuning parameter is picked according to model performance on test data as question states, when generalization error is estimated for picked model, it is estimated on the same test data, and hence gives an overly optimistic result.

C. Nothing implies that the process is computationally inefficient (although it is practically inefficient because of double-dipping into test data).

D. Nothing implies it should NEVER be done, because if test data set is containing almost all of the data in the world, even if complexity is fitted to it, it could still serve as good approximation of generalization error (not overly optimistic).

Does this logic above not hold? I am having extreme trouble with this question. Is it because I am assuming that there is no validation set in this case (I don't see how that would change the right answer, though).

Someone please help me.

Comment: don't you think that it should be D because we use training data for tuning any model.

Comment: As noted above in the explanation for why I picked option A, tuning (a.k.a picking the right complexity by looking at the results from using all the different complexities) the model should not be done on training data because results from all the different complexity models are already trained/optimized on training data. 2nd degree polynomial might better fit training data than 3rd degree, just in this one case. But in reality, 3rd degree might be a better fit. Picking complexity based on this will give the wrong result, so the model must be used to fit unused (test) data, then fix complexity

Comment: My apologies, i read it wrong. You are absolutely right the benefit of a using a validation set or test set is obviously helps in preventing from overfitting(A). But, is the question **consequence** of selecting model complexity on test data? By definition consequence -> typically one that is unwelcome or unpleasant. Then i think B and D should be the answer because A is not a consequence of using test set rather its a benifit. what was the correct answer?

Comment: I think what question means is what if we tune with test data as well as train data. I practice i use cross validation to tune and then test on validation set.

Comment: You got it right! B and D. Strangely, the word 'consequence' was not used in the original question. I had added it myself to better explain the question. Glad it helped! I appreciate the help. Yea, they were looking for the negative consequences of using test data (instead of validation data or training data) - not the positive results.

Comment: I was stuck with the same problem on the same course. My answer was B because I've thought it was not the case of never doing it (D), despite not being a recommended practice.